# Scheduled local notifications in iOS-Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I cannot find a proper tutorial on sending scheduled local notifications

I came up with this but below code is not working

```
void Start()

    {
        LocalNotification notif = new LocalNotification();

        notif.fireDate          = System.DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5f);

        notif.alertBody         = "Hey";    

        NotificationServices.ScheduleLocalNotification(notif);

     }
```

Please help me with this

Comment: Here is the script. http://pastebin.com/Abh9GhP7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this:

```
void ScheduleNotificationForiOSWithMessage (string text, System.DateTime fireDate)
{
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer) {
        LocalNotification notification = new LocalNotification ();
        notification.fireDate = fireDate;
        notification.alertAction = "Alert";
        notification.alertBody = text;
        notification.hasAction = false;
        NotificationServices.ScheduleLocalNotification (notification);

        #if UNITY_IOS
        NotificationServices.RegisterForLocalNotificationTypes (LocalNotificationType.Alert | LocalNotificationType.Badge);
        #endif
    }        
}
```

Comment: It is throwing this error.                                                `UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices' does not contain a definition for `RegisterForLocalNotificationTypes'                                                                            and what should i pass in the second parameter while calling this method.  Thank you for replying.

Comment: for `what should i pass in the second parameter` you can pass `System.DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5f);` this is the date when notification should appear.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call "NotificationServices.RegisterForNotifications" first. 
See => [Unity Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.NotificationServices.RegisterForNotifications.html)

Comment: Hello Marius, Thank you for replying.  I just want scheduled local notifications . i dont want any notifications from a provider

Comment: "Register to receive local **and** remote notifications of the specified types from a provider via Apple Push Service."  You have to register for local notifications aswell.

Comment: The type or namespace name `iOS' does not exist in the namespace `UnityEngine'. Are you missing an assembly reference?                                                The type or namespace name `iOS' does not exist in the namespace `UnityEngine'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
 it is showing these errors on importing the namespace as show in the documentation

Comment: I assume you are using Unity4. => The namespace changed in Unity5
     In Unity4 use   NotificationServices.RegisterForLocalNotificationTypes instead